# SocketRocket IOS Swift unable to re open socket it is crashing

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, websocket, socketrocket

I am using following library for Socket connection https://github.com/facebook/SocketRocket

Following is my code to create socket connection

```
 socketRocket = SRWebSocket(url: URL(string: streamUrl)!)
 socketRocket?.delegate = self
 socketRocket?.open()
```

Now if there is any network error like wifi turned off Socket is disconnected and does not work if even if internet is turned on again

I tried following code to reopen socket but it is not working

```
 socketRocket?.close()
 socketRocket?.open()
```

How to reopen socket or resume socket after network or any other error occurs?

Comment: use SocketIO it reconnects automatically

Comment: can you share link?

Comment: Link to socket.io for iOS: https://socket.io/blog/socket-io-on-ios/

Comment: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift

Comment: heyy does it require any client side implementation as well?